# Wordpress admin panel is blank

Tags: admin, dashboard

When i logged in wordpress admin, the dashboard looks a blank page. Only left side navigations are visible. What might be the problem? Can any one me give solution or idea?

Comment: You will need to give more info. You have had to something for this to happen

Answer (score 3):

Try manually [resetting your plugins.](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

If that does not resolve the issue, manually rename the directory of currently active theme,
This will force the Default theme to activate.
And you find out theme related issue.(theme function can affect the admin panel)

Comment: I tried to rename the plugin folder and currently active theme. Even the default theme is not enabled.